# Как подключиться к локальной базе данных с помощью JDBC?

Tags: java, база-данных

Требуется работать с локальной БД (не на сервере, а просто файл на диске). Вроде задача простая а выполнить не получается

```
public class DatabaseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createNewDatabase("home/saturn/Рабочий стол/test.db");
    }

    private static void createNewDatabase(String path) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql:" + path;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Driver not found.");
        }
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver name: " + meta.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("Database created by path " + path);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, в примерах вижу где передается путь к файлу, значит все таки можно? Стектрейс:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:home/saturn/Рабочий стол/test.db
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:703)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at ru.skyscrapers.server.DatabaseTest.createNewDatabase(DatabaseTest.java:21)
    at ru.skyscrapers.server.DatabaseTest.main(DatabaseTest.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Зависимость есть

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Может стоит воспользоваться SQLite или MS Access для этого?

Comment: @AlexChermenin, а какая разница какой тип бд использовать?

Comment: А jar файл с JDBC вообще в проекте присутствует?

Comment: @RomanDanilov, да, есть, я в pom.xml добавил dependency, пробовал так же драйвер импортировать, все в порядке, иначе бы вывелся ClassNotFoundException

Comment: `jdbc:mysql:home/saturn/Рабочий стол/test.db` попробуйте убрать русские символы из пути (и пробел заодно)

Comment: @Barmaley, поменял на такой путь `jdbc:mysql:test.db` - та же ошибка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не уверен, но все же опубликую это, как ответ.
Ты используешь MySQL, а это всё же серверная СУБД, а не встроенная (embedded). А это значит, что ты должен подключаться к серверу MySQL для работы с БД.
Формат строки подключения следующий:

> jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName

Твой формат несколько отличается, поскольку ты хочешь подключиться к файлу напрямую:

> jdbc:mysql:home/saturn/Рабочий стол/test.db

Мое мнение такое, что приложение начинает искать подходящий драйвер для подключения по твоей строке, соответственно его не находит и ругается на то, что нет подходящего драйвера.

Я бы использовал embedded СУБД, такие как HSQLDB, H2, SQLite и так далее, которые позволяют подключаться именно к файлам СУБД. Например для HSQLDB:

> jdbc:hsqldb:file:*path*

Comment: вот так и думал, что дело в этом, сейчас попробую, а разве можно HSQLDB использовать вместо MySQL? я просто только пробую базы данных и тут эти типы

Comment: мне же ведь так же можно будет слать запросы?

Comment: @Flippy HSQLDB полноценная реляционная СУБД, поддерживающая стандарты SQL-92, SQL:1999, SQL:2003 и SQL:2008. Запросы практически не отличаются от запросов в mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813890/sqlite-or-mysql-how-to-decide - цитата `Sqlite is an embedded database which has no network capabilities (unless you add them).`

Comment: так что я думаю можно использовать sqlite. она точь в точь такая же в использовании как mysql

Comment: SQLite тоже вполне подойдет)

Comment: спасибо! sqlite реально сработал) правда я найти бд не могу, поменяю путь на рабочий стол как было)

Comment: все, появилась, спасибо вам)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще то коннект к MySQL подразумевает, что "поднят" сервис СУБД (то есть СУБД слушает TCP на некоем порту - по умолчанию 3306)

Напрямую к файлу БД коннект в MySQL не поддерживает, то есть строка коннекта к СУБД развернутой на локальном хосте, должна быть типа такая:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=myuser&password=mypassword
```

Comment: понял, спасибо, просто мне нужно было работать с бд локально, без всяких серверов, теперь хоть знать буду)